# Mongoose array null when trying to push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm playing around with Mongoose, and I got the folowing schemas:

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(remoteDbUrl);

autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

var AnswerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Author is required']
  },
  description: String,
  createdAt: { 
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now 
  },
  votes: Number
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);

var QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Author is required']
  },
  headline: String,
  description: String,
  answers: [AnswerSchema],
  createdAt: { 
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now 
  }
}, {timestamps: true});

QuestionSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Question');
module.exports = Question = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

In my db it looks like this:

[image]

After inserting my question this way:

```
const question1 = new Question({
      author: 'TestAuthor',
      headline: 'TestHeadline',
      description: 'TestDescription',
      answers: []
    }
  );

  question1.save().then(result => {
    console.log("Created");
    };
  );
```

It looks all good, but when I try to push to my array, as the answers begin to flow, and I try to add them like this:

```
async function addAnswer(questionId, author, description) {
    const question = await Question.findById(questionId);

    const answer = new Answer({
      author: author,
      description: description
    });

    question.answers.push(answer);
    question.save();
}
```

I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'answers' of null`. What am I missing?

Comment: are you able to print questionId before findById.

Answer (score 0):

No need to find and push answer like that. You can directly search and push your answer by using [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) in mongodb. As follow:

```
async function addAnswer(questionId, author, description) {

    const answer = new Answer({
      author: author,
      description: description
    });

    const question = await Question.findOneAndUpdate(
       { _id: questionId },
       {
          $push: {    
            answers: answer         // Bold Part will be your answer object
          }
       },
       {new: true }                 // To get the updated results in return            
     ).exec()

     console.log('Updated question document: ',question)

}
```